# "contained in text" vs. "contained in texts"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I wonder whether I should write "contained in text" or "contained in text**s**". Example:

> Using natural language processing is necessary to identify information that is contained in text**s**.

The [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contained+in+texts%2C+contained+in+text&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontained%20in%20texts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontained%20in%20text%3B%2Cc0) seems to show that both "contained in text" vs. "contained in texts"  are commonly employed:

[image]

Does that mean that both "contained in text" vs. "contained in texts" are grammatically correct?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the context.  If you're talking about text in the generic sense of written communication, then singular.  If the term is a substitute for "documents" or specific samples of written material, then plural.

Comment: In a computer context, how about "contained in text files"? Or "text in books" or wherever the text is? This would avoid the issue. In any case, these indicate plural usage, so I would go with "texts" (in my mind this means books).

Comment: **using...processing is necessary**  : You can simply say *Natural language processing is necessary....*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/text), when used in the context of computers, **text** is a mass noun referring to data in the form of words or alphabetic characters. It can also be used as a mass noun referring to written or printed words, typically forming a connected piece of work.

**text** can also be a count noun referring to a specific document- a book, magazine article, text message, etc.

Both are therefore grammatically correct, but you should choose **text** if you want to consider text as a bulk item or one document, or **texts** if you want to consider it as a number of separate documents.

Answer (score 1):

While JavaLatte's answer is *correct*, in the context of your example, the subject "natural language processing" refers to the *generic* method to automatically extract information from **text** -- meaning any written language.

Unless there is additional context to support the idea that the algorithm is meant to read from multiple written sources, **texts** would not be appropriate.